# Frequent update table view failed on swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview need to be updated very second. The code are as following. I design the headerview to have a dropdown function, when the header tap the rest are displayed. The code will crashes when I am trying to tap the header, the thread stops, xcode is not giving any hint on how and why.

```
func didListOfBLEDevicesUpdate(newDevice: BLEDevice)
{
  println("receivedDevice from scanner every second: \(newDevice.deviceName)")
    self.deviceTableView.reloadData()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return BLEDevice.listOfDevices.items.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return BLEDevice.listOfDevices.items[section].deviceName
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if(IsExpandedMode[indexPath.section] == true){
        return 400
    }
    return 70;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    headerView.tag = section

    let headerString = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: tableView.frame.size.width-10, height: 30)) as UILabel
    headerString.text = BLEDevice.listOfDevices.items[section].deviceName
    headerView .addSubview(headerString)
    let headerTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer (target: self, action:"sectionHeaderTapped:")
    headerView .addGestureRecognizer(headerTapped)
    return headerView
}

func sectionHeaderTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    println("Tapping working")
    println(recognizer.view?.tag)


    var indexPath : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection:(recognizer.view?.tag as Int!)!)
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

        var collapsed = self.IsExpandedMode [indexPath.section]
        collapsed = !collapsed;

        self.IsExpandedMode[indexPath.section] = collapsed
        //reload specific section animated
        var range = NSMakeRange(indexPath.section, 1)
        var sectionToReload = NSIndexSet(indexesInRange: range)
        self.deviceTableView.reloadSections(sectionToReload, withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    }
 }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : DeviceTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell

      let row = indexPath.row
    cell.deviceName!.text = BLEDevice.listOfDevices.items[row].deviceName
    cell.connectionStatus.text = BLEDevice.listOfDevices.items[row].connectionStatus
    cell.deviceSignalStrengthen.text = BLEDevice.listOfDevices.items[row].RSSI
    cell.manufacturerData.text = BLEDevice.listOfDevices.items[row].advertisementPackage.cBAdvertisementDataManufacturerData
    cell.serviceUUID.text = BLEDevice.listOfDevices.items[row].advertisementPackage.cBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDs
    cell.serviceData.text = DataConvertHelper.getNSDictionary(BLEDevice.listOfDevices.items[row].advertisementPackage.cBAdvertisementDataServiceData)
    cell.TxPowerLevel.text = BLEDevice.listOfDevices.items[row].advertisementPackage.cBAdvertisementDataTxPowerLevel
    cell.IsConnectable.text = DataConvertHelper.getBool(BLEDevice.listOfDevices.items[row].advertisementPackage.cBAdvertisementDataIsConnectable)
    cell.solicitedServiceUUID.text = BLEDevice.listOfDevices.items[row].advertisementPackage.cBAdvertisementDataSolicitedServiceUUIDs
    cell.shortenedLocalName.text = BLEDevice.listOfDevices.items[row].advertisementPackage.cBAdvertisementDataLocalName
      return cell
}
```

Comment: Is `didListOfBLEDevicesUpdate` being called on a timer and is it on the main thread? What do you mean by thread stops? You said that the table updates every second. If that is happening in a background thread, then you could be changing the model while you try and do a table reload. I think you need to add more detail to the question on what is happening and what you are seeing: e.g. Does the tap gesture code finish or crash mid code: if so where etc....

Comment: didListOfBLEDevicesUpdate is called on a timer. My goal is to make a tableview to show a list of devices and each row shall have a header and when tap the header the row drops down and dhow the detail of the device.

Comment: And is the timer on the main thread or a background thread? I also take it this timer finds the new devices before calling this method? Would be worth you showing that code as well. Timer setup and timer methods.

Comment: Rather than trying to detect taps on section headers, you might be better to always make row 0 of a given section a custom title cell. Then you can use standard cell selection and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Also wondered why `section` is never used in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? Seems you only use `row` which is odd for a section based table?

Comment: This is the error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (14) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (13), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (1 inserted, 1 deleted).'"

*** First throw call stack:     This list might updated bcz new devices are added into the dictionary at runtime,

Comment: To me it looks like you are confusing rows and sections. You always return 1 for the number of rows in a section and your devices seem indexed in the data model by `section` as the number of sections is the size of the `BLEDevice.listOfDevices.items.count`. However in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you ignore section completely and use row which will always be 0. To me it looks like you should be using `[section]` and not `[row]` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: The error you are getting is implying that you added & deleted a row in the table somewhere but the data model is saying it thinks it has increased by 1. Check any code which removes a row and make sure you removed the row from your data model. This must be in code we cannot see.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions if I want to implement a dropdown for a single row?

Comment: Added answer with suggestion on an approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use reload sections and reload rows rather than reloading data

Answer (score 0):

The method you have used to handle the table seems to be rather complex. An alternative would be as follows:

1) Assumption from you code is that each device is associated with a section. As noted in the comments, your `cellForRorAtIndexPath` method seems to be using `[row]` to index your data model, but the model is based on `[section]` as you always return the number of rows as 1 for every section and the number of sections is the number of devices.

2) Rather than using a header view for each section and having to add gesture recognizers, simply create a custom cell to represent the device and make this row 0 of the section.

3) So each device is associated with a section, and row 0 of each section is the header information cell, NOT a header view. Make the header view nil. You can use a header height to leave a gap between sections.

4) Add code to detect selection of cells. When the cell row is 0, its the header cell. If the device is collapsed, set it to be expanded and vice versa and reload the section.

5) Make a new custom cell for you dropdown information. this will be row 1 of any section which is showing information.

6) Update your number of rows in section to return 2 if expanded, or 1 if collapsed.

7) Update `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to return the header cell for row 0 and the detail cell for row 1. Make sure to fix the `[row]` indexing to be `[section]` indexing.

This gives you a table of device header cells, which when clicked insert a detail cell below and when clicked again remove it and no gesture recognizers needed.

You need to make sure that your data model updates are working correctly. Seems from your errors that you are not updating the data model properly: in particular removal of devices.